# Why cannot open Ubuntu-tweak after installing Pantheon greeter?

Tags: console, ubuntu-tweak

My problem is I cannot open Ubuntu-Tweak (my OS is Ubuntu 14.04). Of course reinstalled from synaptic and nothing. Last thing I did was to Install Panther-greeter from Elementary OS, but didn't touched the schemes manually. In the other hand, Unity-Tweak still works, but still need the Ubuntu-tweak.

Here is what appears when opening from console:

> compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings compizconfig - Info:
>   Integration : true compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak", line 94, in
>   on_startup
>       self._window = UbuntuTweakWindow(feature=options.feature, module=options.module, splash_window=splash_window)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 293, in
>   **init**
>       tweaks_page = FeaturePage('tweaks')   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 161, in
>   **init**
>       self._setting = GSetting('com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.%s' % feature_name)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/gsettings.py",
>   line 19, in **init**
>       self.schema_default = self.default or Schema.load_schema(self.schema_id, self.key)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/common.py",
>   line 129, in load_schema
>       tree = etree.parse(open(schema_path))   File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3239, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:69955)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102257)   File "parser.pxi", line 1789, in
>   lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102516)
>   File "parser.pxi", line 1684, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101442)   File "parser.pxi", line 1134, in
>   lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97069)   File "parser.pxi", line 582, in
>   lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91275)   File "parser.pxi", line 683, in
>   lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92461)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91757) lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: StartTag:
>   invalid element name, line 1, column 2 TypeError: can't convert return
>   value to desired type /usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak:123: Warning:
>   g_value_copy: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (src_value)' failed
>   app.run(sys.argv) /usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak:123: Warning: g_value_reset:
>   assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed   app.run(sys.argv)
>   /usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak:123: Warning: g_value_unset: assertion
>   'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed   app.run(sys.argv)